# How can i import a HTML + JQuery image in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, import, image-gallery

i have this site (www.aviationphoto.it) with about 12.000 image in HTML, CSS and JQuery. I'd like to import all image gallery in new Wordpress site (demosite.comuv.com).

How can i do that?

Thank's much.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to automate the moving of images from one site to Wordpress. By Default, Wordpress will not recognise images unless they are added through the dashboard.

I did manage to find this link for you which explains how to FTP you images to the Wordpress server and then import them into Wordpress from there.

http://wpmu.org/how-to-bulk-upload-files-to-the-wordpress-media-library-using-ftp/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the images in the previous site in a specific folder? If so, cant you just import the folder to wordpress media library?

One option could be to use a plugin, for example: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-html-pages/

Comment: Hello, thanks for our reply. Yes i have the image in a specific folder (with the years name). But how can i do to import all gallery with the thumbnail and description name?

Answer (score 0):

Or I've used this in the past:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-importer/

You might have to view the html source and ensure the path to the images is correct and doesn't point to the old domain.  But it works for me ...